# Add single rel value to all <a> in parent and also add incremental rel values to <a> of sibling parents

Tags: jquery

Horrible title I know. I'm looking to apply a specific rel value to all child `<a>` within a parent, in this case `.wrap`. All rel values should be the same within a particular instance of `.wrap`, but between each individual `.wrap` (i.e. the siblings of a parent) the rel values should have a numeric distinction.

In the example below this rel value takes the form of `rel="type-X"` where X is the incremental numeric value. This is what I want.

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div><a rel="type-1" href="#"></a></div>
    <div><a rel="type-1" href="#"></a></div>
    <div><a rel="type-1" href="#"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><a rel="type-2" href="#"></a></div>
    <div><a rel="type-2" href="#"></a></div>
    <div><a rel="type-2" href="#"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><a rel="type-3" href="#"></a></div>
    <div><a rel="type-3" href="#"></a></div>
    <div><a rel="type-3" href="#"></a></div>
</div>
```

The best I've been able to come up with so far is to either either apply the same rel value to all instances of `.wrap a` (so just one instance of rel="type-1" in all 3 .wrap) or I'm applying a new rel value to each `<a>` (and end up with rel="type-1" to rel="type-9")

```
var i = 0;
$('.wrap').find(function () {
    i ++;
    $(this).find('a').attr('rel', 'type-' + i);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write:

```
$('.wrap').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).find('a').attr('rel', 'type-' + (index + 1));
});
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('.wrap').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).find('a').attr('rel', 'type-' + (index + 1));
  });
  
  $('#txtarea').text($('#myBlock').html())
  .height($('#txtarea')[0].scrollHeight);
  
  $('#addRel').on('click', function(e) {
     $('.wrap').each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).find('a').attr('rel', 'type-' + (index + 1));
     });
    $('#txtarea').text($('#myBlock').html());
  });

  $('#removeRel').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.wrap').each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).find('a').removeAttr('rel');
     });
    $('#txtarea').text($('#myBlock').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="myBlock">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<textarea id="txtarea" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
<button id='addRel'>Add Rel Attr</button>
<button id='removeRel'>Remove Rel Attr</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.wrap').each(function(i,v) {
    $(v).find('a').attr('rel', 'type-' + i); // 1st run will be type-0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need to use jQuery, then this is quite possible in native JavaScript (albeit this is written in ECMAScript 6/ECMAScript 2015):

```js
// converting the results from document.querySelectorAll() into an
// Array.
// Using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the array elements
// held in that Array:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.wrap')).forEach(function(wrap, index) {
  // wrap: (the first argument) is the current array element of
  // the array over which we're iterating,
  // index: (the second argument) is the index of the current
  // array-element within that array.

  // finding the <a> elements within the current div.wrap element,
  // converting that collection into an Array, again using
  // Array.from(), and then again iterative over the elements
  // using Array.prototype.forEach().
  Array.from(wrap.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(function(a) {
    // a: (the first argument) again refers to the current
    // array-element of the array over which we're iterating.

    // setting the attribute 'rel' to the value of the string
    // 'type-' concatenated with the number formed by the addition
    // of the index variable (the outer forEach()) added to the
    // number 1:
    a.setAttribute('rel', 'type-' + (index + 1));
  });
});
```

```css
div.wrap {
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
}
a::before {
  content: 'rel="' attr(rel)'"';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```